# Google App Engine App data reset on localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine, localhost

I've noticed my google app engine app that I'm developing on my local host is being reset every night, even though I am only running it with the command `dev_appserver.py .` and not explicitly resetting the data.

The data/app persists during the day but seems to be reset every night. I've checked the admin dashboard but did not find any settings pertaining to this.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dev server puts the datastore in a temp directory, and it resets every time you start.  If you want the local datastore to persist, make/use a real directory, and use the datastore_path flag:

```
--datastore_path=/path/to/your/datastore/directory/dev_appserver.datastore
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Just to clarify (new to GAE and programming in general), should I type the following in the terminal:
`--datestore_path=/pathtodatafolder/dev_appserver.datastore` ?

And should this data_folder be in the same directory as my application?

Comment: The directory should not be in your application, as you don't want to upload it to production.  You could use a `skip_files` in your app.yaml, but that's a separate discussion.

`--datastore_path` is a flag on your dev_appserver.py command.

For a beginner, I recommend using the GoogleAppEngineLauncher app.  It makes it easy to configure these things.

Comment: When I use this solution I am getting this error: google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8080

Comment: Suat Atan PhD That has nothing to do with this answer.  Sounds like you have another app on your 8080 port.  Try stopping the other app, or restarting your machine